# Robocopy all files in a folder except that folder

Tags: powershell, parameters, robocopy

I want to know how to robocopy all files in a folder except for that folder.

So, I have

```
Folder A
    >Int Folder B
    >Int Folder C
```

So I want to copy Folder B and C but not take Folder A.

Will `robocopy $source 'Folder A'` do it or do I need a specific switch?

I suspect the above might take folder A aswell?

Comment: run robocopy twice, once for B and once for C...

Comment: I would like it to be more dynamic than that as this is just an example and could be lots of things in there I don't know about. IE. I could have a directory tree of which I don't know what it is

Comment: the only depth-related option is `/lev`, which lops off deep directories. there isn't one to say "start copying 2 levels down"

Comment: What I need is to copy everything in a directory but not take that directory

Comment: Does the tag "PowerShell" mean that we can use PowerShell? Because it happens to be really good at wildcarding. :-) Can't you just do `dir a\*|robocopy...` (or `dir -directory`) with appropriate parameters for RC -- that is, run Robocopy multiple times *but* dynamically?

Comment: then a `for` loop to work on all the subdirs would do the trick.

Comment: This robocopy is part of a powershell script.

Comment: Could you show me an example of how that would work please?

Comment: Take a look at Exclude parameter in  Get-ChildItem cmdlet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you actually tried it? robocopy will sync the folders contents, so if `$source = "c:\folder a"` then `folder a` will not be copied, only it's content.

```
Get-ChildItem '.\Folder A' -Recurse | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Fullname

C:\Users\Frode\Desktop\Folder A\Int Folder B
C:\Users\Frode\Desktop\Folder A\Int Folder C
C:\Users\Frode\Desktop\Folder A\Int Folder B\folderb-file.txt
C:\Users\Frode\Desktop\Folder A\Int Folder C\folderc-file - Copy.txt
C:\Users\Frode\Desktop\Folder A\Int Folder C\folderc-file.txt

$source = "C:\Users\Frode\Desktop\Folder A"

robocopy $source 'Dest' /S


Get-ChildItem .\Dest -Recurse | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Fullname

C:\Users\Frode\Desktop\Dest\Int Folder B
C:\Users\Frode\Desktop\Dest\Int Folder C
C:\Users\Frode\Desktop\Dest\Int Folder B\folderb-file.txt
C:\Users\Frode\Desktop\Dest\Int Folder C\folderc-file - Copy.txt
C:\Users\Frode\Desktop\Dest\Int Folder C\folderc-file.txt
```

Comment: That S switch, I didn't have that. Let me try that and update you.